# KiCAD's eeschema: How to move a reference / value in a schematic?

Tags: schematics, kicad

I would like to arrange a component's reference or value label in a eeschema schematic but I cannot seem to select or move it.

If I try to edit the respective field's X and Y position via the "Symbol Properties" dialog, it does not have any effect and resets the values automatically.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Place cursor over the reference text.
2. Press M.
3. Move to place of choice
4. Click mouse to release.

Comment: Thanks, I think I might have tried to **G**rab it before...

Comment: The context menu (RMB on the field text [reference/value]) also tells the available commands (I also managed to only get the component commands previously).